# Editing entries with Channel Form not working

Tags: safecracker, forms

I've created a bunch of simple entries for a channel, and I'd like guest users to be able to edit the entries.  The entries are all on the index page, since this is a one-page site.  No matter what I try, my Channel Form will not update the entries.  This is basically straight from the docs, but submitting the form doesn't change any of the fields.  Here's my code:

```
{exp:channel:entries
 channel="products"
 disable="categories|member_data|pagination|trackbacks"
 dynamic="no"
}

<img src="{product_image}" class="pure-img">
    {exp:channel:form channel="products" return="product/index" url_title="{url_title}"}
 <input name="title" type="text" value="{title}">
 {field:product_description}
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
{/exp:channel:form}

        {/exp:channel:entries}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you set 'allow guest posts' to the channel? http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_form/index.html#allowing-guests-to-post-entries

Comment: Yep.  And I'm also logged in as a Super Admin, so you'd think I'd be able to post no matter what...

Answer (score 0):

Take the exp:channel:entries tags away....

Comment: Hi Nutmeg, what do you mean take the exp:channel:entries tags away? Does something else go there or is it blank? Please clarify.

Comment: Hi fmz, remove the channel entries tag and only use the channel form tags and write bac with any results....

Comment: I have done that on mine, but it doesn't save the changes. Please see: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/25460/channel-form-edits-not-sticking

Comment: Ok, fmz it's a bit of a stab in the dark as I don't know your custom fields and other template segments, but working with Channel Forms often has Javascript/Jquery issues due too other add ons which rely on this. Try switching off certain decencies by adding include_assets="no" within your Channel Form Tags. If this doesn't resolve the issue you will need to provide more details....

Answer (score 0):

change the url_title on the channel form tag

```
    {exp:channel:form channel="products" return="product/index" url_title="{url_title}"}
 <input name="title" type="text" value="{title}">
 {field:product_description}
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
{/exp:channel:form}
```

to `url_title="{segment_1}"`