# Channel Form Edits Not "Sticking"

Tags: safecracker

I created a channel:form for creating entries and it works fine. However, when I attempt to edit the content of the entry, the edits don't take and it returns the original entry values.

Edits to the same entry in the Control Panel save fine, so there is something wrong with my form.

Here is the code for the edit entry form:

```
{exp:channel:form channel="facilities" entry_id="{segment_3}" author_id="CURRENT_USER"  return="test/preview/ENTRY_ID" }

<input type="hidden" id="facilityCounter" value="1" />
 <div id="facilities">
   <fieldset class="facility-info">

    <dl>
    <dt><label>Facility Name*</label></dt>
    <dd class="validate"><input type="text" name="{title}" class="required" value="{title}"></dd>

    <dt><label>Street address*</label></dt>
    <dd class="validate"><input type="text" name="{facility_street_address}" class="required" value="{facility_street_address}"></dd>

    <table class="city-state-zip">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">City*</th>
                <th scope="col">State*</th>
                <th scope="col">Zip*</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="validate"><input type="text" name="{facility_city}" class="required"  value="{facility_city}"></td>
                <td>
                            <select name="{facility_state}">
                            <option selected value="{facility_state}">{facility_state}</option>
                            <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                            <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                        <option value="FL">Florida</option>
                        <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
                        <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
                        <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
                        <option value="MI">Mississippi</option>
                        <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
                        <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
                        <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
                     </select>

                </td>
                <td class="validate"><input type="text" name="{facility_zip}" class="zip required" value="{facility_zip}"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="image" src="/photos/btn_submit-survey.png" alt="" value="Submit">
</div>
</div><!-- end div.facility-form -->

{/exp:channel:form}
```

I have confirmed permission and do not receive any errors. I would appreciate any insights into why the edits are not saving.

Comment: I don't see "author_id" listed as a parameter in the documentation.  https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_form/index.html#parameters

Comment: Even with that removed it still does not save edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently have:

```
name="{facility_state}"
```

I think this should be:

```
name="facility_state"
```

Same applies to your other fields.

Comment: To the all-seeing-eye. Thank you! That solved it.

Comment: Follow up question. In the case of checkbox fields with there are two options, yes or no, what should the name="" value be set as? I currently have field_name[], but that is not working.

Comment: Recommend you post this as a separate question.

Comment: I posted it here: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/25473/channel-form-checkbox-fields-not-saving-on-edit thanks.