# Channel Form checkbox fields not saving on edit

Tags: safecracker

I have a channel form with several checkbox fields. They go in fine but when I try to edit the form content the edits do not save. The rest of the fields save when edited so I am looking for how to modify the checkbox fields and have them save properly.

Here is the code for the entire form.

```
{exp:channel:form channel="facilities" url_title="{segment_3}" author_id="CURRENT_USER"  return="supply-chain/facility-preview/ENTRY_ID" }

    <input type="hidden" id="facilityCounter" value="1" />
     <div id="facilities">
       <fieldset class="facility-info">

        <dl>
        <dt><label>Facility Name*</label></dt>
        <dd class="validate"><input type="text" name="title" class="required" value="{title}"></dd>

        <dt><label>Street address*</label></dt>
        <dd class="validate"><input type="text" name="facility_street_address" class="required" value="{facility_street_address}"></dd>

        <table class="city-state-zip">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">City*</th>
                    <th scope="col">State*</th>
                    <th scope="col">Zip*</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="validate"><input type="text" name="facility_city" class="required"  value="{facility_city}"></td>
                    <td><!--<input type="text" name="facility[1][facility_state]" value="">-->
                                <select name="facility_state">
                                <option selected value="{facility_state}">{facility_state}</option>
                                <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                                <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                            <option value="FL">Florida</option>
                            <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
                            <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
                            <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
                            <option value="MI">Mississippi</option>
                            <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
                            <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
                            <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
                         </select>

                    </td>
                    <td class="validate"><input type="text" name="facility_zip" class="zip required" value="{facility_zip}"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <dt><label>Facility description*</label></dt>
        <dd class="validate"><textarea name="facility_description" class="required">
        {exp:eehive_hacksaw}
                {facility_description}
        {/exp:eehive_hacksaw}
        </textarea></dd>
            </dl>

        <p>This facility supplies components or services for:</p>

            <table class="survey">

                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
                        <th scope="col">Currently<br />Supply</th>
                        <th scope="col">Don't Currently<br /> But Could Supply</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="nacelle">
                        <td>Nacelle</td>
                        <td><img src="/photos/arrow_down.png" alt=""><input type="checkbox" name="nacelle[data][]" value="{nacelle}" {if nacelle == "current-supply"}checked="yes"{/if}></td>
                        <td><img src="/photos/arrow_down.png" alt=""><input type="checkbox" name="nacelle[data][]" value="{nacelle}" {if nacelle == "could-supply"}checked="yes"{/if}></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr class="nacelle-group">
                        <td class="title">Drivetrain / Gearbox</td>
                        <td><img src="/photos/spacer.gif" alt=""><input type="checkbox" name="drivetrain_gearbox[data][]" value="{drivetrain_gearbox}" {if drivetrain_gearbox == "current-supply"}checked="yes"{/if}></td>
                        <td><img src="/photos/spacer.gif" alt=""><input type="checkbox" name="drivetrain_gearbox[data][]" value="{drivetrain_gearbox}" {if drivetrain_gearbox == "could-supply"}checked="yes"{/if}></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr class="nacelle-group">
                        <td class="title">Generator / Electrical</td>
                        <td><img src="/photos/spacer.gif" alt=""><input type="checkbox" name="generator_electrical[data][]" value="{generator_electrical}" {if generator_electrical == "current-supply"}checked="yes"{/if}></td>
                        <td><img src="/photos/spacer.gif" alt=""><input type="checkbox" name="generator_electrical[data][]" value="{generator_electrical}" {if generator_electrical == "could-supply"}checked="yes"{/if}></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr class="nacelle-group">
                        <td class="title">Control System</td>
                        <td><img src="/photos/spacer.gif" alt=""><input type="checkbox" name="control_system[data][]" value="{control_system}" {if control_system == "current-supply"}checked="yes"{/if}></td>
                        <td><img src="/photos/spacer.gif" alt=""><input type="checkbox" name="control_system[data][]" value="{control_system}" {if control_system == "could-supply"}checked="yes"{/if}></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr class="nacelle-group">
                        <td class="title">Yaw / Pitch</td>
                        <td><img src="/photos/spacer.gif" alt=""><input type="checkbox" name="yaw_pitch[data][]" value="{yaw_pitch}" {if yaw_pitch == "current-supply"}checked="yes"{/if}></td>
                        <td><img src="/photos/spacer.gif" alt=""><input type="checkbox" name="yaw_pitch[data][]" value="{yaw_pitch}" {if yaw_pitch == "could-supply"}checked="yes"{/if}></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr class="nacelle-group">
                        <td class="title">Housing</td>
                        <td><img src="/photos/spacer.gif" alt=""><input type="checkbox" name="housing[data][]" value="{housing}" {if housing == "current-supply"}checked="yes"{/if}></td>
                        <td><img src="/photos/spacer.gif" alt=""><input type="checkbox" name="housing[data][]" value="{housing}" {if housing == "could-supply"}checked="yes"{/if}></td>
                    </tr>


                    <tr class="professional">
                        <td>Professional Services</td>
                        <td><img src="/photos/arrow_down.png" alt=""><input type="checkbox" name="professional_services[data][]" value="{professional_services}" {if professional_services == "current-supply"}checked="yes"{/if}></td>
                        <td><img src="/photos/arrow_down.png" alt=""><input type="checkbox" name="professional_services[data][]" value="{professional_services}" {if professional_services == "could-supply"}checked="yes"{/if}></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr class="professional-group">
                        <td class="title">Engineering</td>
                        <td><img src="/photos/spacer.gif" alt=""><input type="checkbox" name="engineering[data][]" value="{engineering}" {if engineering == "current-supply"}checked="yes"{/if}></td>
                        <td><img src="/photos/spacer.gif" alt=""><input type="checkbox" name="engineering[data][]" value="{engineering}" {if engineering == "could-supply"}checked="yes"{/if}></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr class="professional-group">
                        <td class="title">Environmental Services</td>
                        <td><img src="/photos/spacer.gif" alt=""><input type="checkbox" name="environmental_services[data][]" value="{environmental_services}" {if environmental_services == "current-supply"}checked="yes"{/if}></td>
                        <td><img src="/photos/spacer.gif" alt=""><input type="checkbox" name="environmental_services[data][]" value="{environmental_services}" {if environmental_services == "could-supply"}checked="yes"{/if}></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr class="professional-group">
                        <td class="title">Law / Finance</td>
                        <td><img src="/photos/spacer.gif" alt=""><input type="checkbox" name="law_finance[data][]" value="{law_finance}" {if law_finance == "current-supply"}checked="yes"{/if}></td>
                        <td><img src="/photos/spacer.gif" alt=""><input type="checkbox" name="law_finance[data][]" value="{law_finance}" {if law_finance == "could-supply"}checked="yes"{/if}></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr class="professional-group">
                        <td class="title">Other Consulting</td>
                        <td><img src="/photos/spacer.gif" alt=""><input type="checkbox" name="other_consulting[data][]" value="{other_consulting}" {if other_consulting == "current-supply"}checked="yes"{/if}></td>
                        <td><img src="/photos/spacer.gif" alt=""><input type="checkbox" name="other_consulting[data][]" value="{other_consulting}" {if other_consulting == "could-supply"}checked="yes"{/if}></td>
                    </tr>


                    <tr class="services">
                        <td>Field Services</td>
                        <td><img src="/photos/arrow_down.png" alt=""><input type="checkbox" name="field_services[data][]" value="{field_services}" {if field_services == "current-supply"}checked="yes"{/if}></td>
                        <td><img src="/photos/arrow_down.png" alt=""><input type="checkbox" name="field_services[data][]" value="{field_services}" {if field_services == "could-supply"}checked="yes"{/if}></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr class="services-group">
                        <td class="title">Construction</td>
                        <td><img src="/photos/spacer.gif" alt=""><input type="checkbox" name="construction[data][]" value="{construction}" {if construction == "current-supply"}checked="yes"{/if}></td>
                        <td><img src="/photos/spacer.gif" alt=""><input type="checkbox" name="construction[data][]" value="{construction}" {if construction == "could-supply"}checked="yes"{/if}></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr class="services-group">
                        <td class="title">Logistics / Transportation</td>
                        <td><img src="/photos/spacer.gif" alt=""><input type="checkbox" name="logistics_transportation[data][]" value="{logistics_transportation}" {if logistics_transportation == "current-supply"}checked="yes"{/if}></td>
                        <td><img src="/photos/spacer.gif" alt=""><input type="checkbox" name="logistics_transportation[data][]" value="{logistics_transportation}" {if logistics_transportation == "could-supply"}checked="yes"{/if}></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr class="services-group">
                        <td class="title">Operations &amp; Maintenance</td>
                        <td><img src="/photos/spacer.gif" alt=""><input type="checkbox" name="operations_maintenance[data][]" value="{operations_maintenance}" {if operations_maintenance == "current-supply"}checked="yes"{/if}></td>
                        <td><img src="/photos/spacer.gif" alt=""><input type="checkbox" name="operations_maintenance[data][]" value="{operations_maintenance}" {if operations_maintenance == "could-supply"}checked="yes"{/if}></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr class="services-group">
                        <td class="title">Other Services</td>
                        <td><img src="/photos/spacer.gif" alt=""><input type="checkbox" name="other_services[data][]" value="{other_services}" {if other_services == "current-supply"}checked="yes"{/if}></td>
                        <td><img src="/photos/spacer.gif" alt=""><input type="checkbox" name="other_services[data][]" value="{other_services}" {if other_services == "could-supply"}checked="yes"{/if}></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr class="singleton">
                        <td>Blades / Rotor</td>
                        <td><img src="/photos/spacer.gif" alt=""><input type="checkbox" name="blades[data][]" value="{blades}" {if blades == "current-supply"}checked="yes"{/if}></td>
                        <td><img src="/photos/spacer.gif" alt=""><input type="checkbox" name="blades[data][]" value="{blades}" {if blades == "could-supply"}checked="yes"{/if}></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr class="singleton">
                        <td>Tower</td>
                        <td><img src="/photos/spacer.gif" alt=""><input type="checkbox" name="tower[data][]" value="{tower}" {if tower == "current-supply"}checked="yes"{/if}></td>
                        <td><img src="/photos/spacer.gif" alt=""><input type="checkbox" name="tower[data][]" value="{tower}" {if tower == "could-supply"}checked="yes"{/if}></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr class="singleton">
                        <td>Foundation</td>
                        <td><img src="/photos/spacer.gif" alt=""><input type="checkbox" name="foundation[data][]" value="{foundation}" {if foundation == "current-supply"}checked="yes"{/if}></td>
                        <td><img src="/photos/spacer.gif" alt=""><input type="checkbox" name="foundation[data][]" value="{foundation}" {if foundation == "could-supply"}checked="yes"{/if}></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr class="singleton">
                        <td>Transmission / Electrical</td>
                        <td><img src="/photos/spacer.gif" alt=""><input type="checkbox" name="transmission_electrical_services[data][]" value="{transmission_electrical_services}" {if transmission_electrical_services == "current-supply"}checked="yes"{/if}></td>
                        <td><img src="/photos/spacer.gif" alt=""><input type="checkbox" name="transmission_electrical_services[data][]" value="{transmission_electrical_services}" {if transmission_electrical_services == "could-supply"}checked="yes"{/if}></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr class="singleton">
                        <td>Marine Trades</td>
                        <td><img src="/photos/spacer.gif" alt=""><input type="checkbox" name="marine_trades[data][]" value="{marine_trades}" {if marine_trades == "current-supply"}checked="yes"{/if}></td>
                        <td><img src="/photos/spacer.gif" alt=""><input type="checkbox" name="marine_trades[data][]" value="{marine_trades}" {if marine_trades == "could-supply"}checked="yes"{/if}></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr class="singleton">
                        <td>Research / Academic / Workforce Development</td>
                        <td><img src="/photos/spacer.gif" alt=""><input type="checkbox" name="research_academic_workforce_dev[data][]" value="{research_academic_workforce_dev}" {if research_academic_workforce_dev == "current-supply"}checked="yes"{/if}></td>
                        <td><img src="/photos/spacer.gif" alt=""><input type="checkbox" name="research_academic_workforce_dev[data][]" value="{research_academic_workforce_dev}" {if research_academic_workforce_dev == "could-supply"}checked="yes"{/if}></td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </fieldset> 
        <div class="clearer"></div>
        <input type="image" src="/photos/btn_submit-survey.png" alt="" value="Submit">
    </div>
</div><!-- end div.facility-form -->

    {/exp:channel:form}
```

However, neither one works. What is the correct way to accomplish this?

Comment: Hi again @fmz.  Here's a hint to get you started: let EE loop through the checkboxes.  See docs: https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/custom_fields.html#checkbox-fields

Comment: Hi AllInOne, this is a very customized form and not one that I believe would work well with the loop. I have edited the question to include the entire form.

Comment: Isn't it as simple as: <input type="checkbox" name="drivetrain_gearbox" value="current-supply" {if drivetrain_gearbox == "current-supply"}checked="yes"{/if}>

Comment: So what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Just add a hidden field name called **checkbox_fields** with list of all checkbox which you use in Channel Forms.

```
<input type="hidden" name="checkbox_fields" value="checkbox_field_1|checkbox_field_2|checkbox_field_3">
```